# How to get notified when SMS Status changes from 'Queued' to 'Sent'?

Tags: sms, twilio, notify

Hello,

        I am trying to learn Twilio API.

        When I [send SMS through php][1] script.. twilio returns a response object with status = 'queued'. Now I want to get notified when the status changes to 'sent'. Is this possible with Twilio??? and if yes then could any body advise me on how to implement his.

        And how to add 'StatusCallback' url

```
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
            // the number we are sending from, must be a valid Twilio number
            "000-000-0000", 

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            "0000000000",

            // the sms body
            "Hey Friend, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
        );
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're on the right track looking to the `StatusCallback`. When using the Twilio PHP Library any optional parameters can be set using an array as the last argument.

```
<?php
$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
  "1235551234", 
  "1235554321",
  "Hey Friend, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!",
  array('StatusCallback' => 'http://example.com/sms/status.php')
);
```

When the message is sent (or if it fails) the data will be passed to the `StatusCallback` url.

Comment: @Tim Lytle , Can you say what are the StatusCallback URL result ?

Comment: @Elby Documented here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the data looks like? Is it in the post parameters? Is it JSON or XML? What does the post look like so I can get the data points in my WEB API service?

Comment: @EJC It's HTTP params, you can set the method using `StatusCallbackMethod`.

Comment: @TimLytle can you tell what are the params in case of failed/undelivered state? I cannot emulate a fail case with a trial account. In case of success I get `SmsSid`, `SmsStatus`, `MessageStatus`, `To`, `MessageSid`, `AccountSid`, `From`, `ApiVersion`. I am more interested in something like errorMessage or errorDescription. I have read the docs they have mentioned just about errorCode which is a numeric code. Not of much help.