# how to get the status of twillio sending sms

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

i m trying to send a SMS from my trail Twilio account. so please help to get sms response/status

```
$client = new Client(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN);
    $client->messages->create(
        $mobile,
        array(
            'from' => TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER,
            'body' => $mobile_message,
            //'statusCallback' => "https://requestb.in/v9uqy6v9"
            'statusCallback' => base_url()."sms_status.php"
        )
    );

    //$status = file_get_contents('https://requestb.in/v9uqy6v9');
    $status = file_get_contents(base_url()."sms_status.php");
```

when i run the above code i got error:

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://.../sms_status.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

while i manually browse the sms_status.php file url than it's not got any error

i also follow this  link [How to get notified when SMS Status changes from 'Queued' to 'Sent'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430003/how-to-get-notified-when-sms-status-changes-from-queued-to-sent)

so please help me to resolve above problem and also define what will be format of output like json/text/array.....

Comment: Is `base_url()` returning something valid that makes a valid, externally accessible, web address when concatenated with "sms_status.php" ?

Comment: yes, it's return base url of web

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set a `statusCallback` URL for an SMS message that you send, the URL needs to point to an application that can handle an incoming HTTP request.

When the status of the SMS message changes through queued, failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered Twilio will make an HTTP POST request to your URL, sending all the [standard request parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) as well as two extra parameters; `MessageStatus` and `ErrorCode`. The parameters will be sent as URL encoded form parameters, so you should be able to read them using PHP's `$_REQUEST[]` syntax.

So, make sure your application can receive HTTP requests at the `statusCallback` URL and you can log the data out from there however you want to.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It would be tough for me to share your code ;) I don't know what you want to do with it.

Comment: i just  want status code and message only, if message is not possible then you can avoid it

Comment: Hello, I can't write your code for you. I don't know what you want to do with the status or the code. What have you tried so far since I answered this?

Comment: file sms_status.php  is use to get message send status how to retrive this status

Comment: It is not used to get the message status, when the message status updates, Twilio will send an HTTP request to `sms_status.php`. That is why it needs to be able to receive incoming requests and then do something with the data.

Comment: ok, your means , i need to handle twilio request and save status in db or any another json file using file sms_status.php and then get response from there not from sms_status.php

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it!